# Can't call VB.NET COM DLL function with String from VBA

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, dll, unmanaged

I implemented a VB.NET DLL with a simple test function:

```
<ComVisible(True)>  
Function TestString ( <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> xyz As String) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> String
Dim y As Integer
    TestString = "Hello"
End Function
```

The function is dead simple. In VBA I declare the function appropriately:

```
Public Declare Function TestString Lib "myDLL.dll" (xyz As String) As String
```

From VBA I also obviously load the DLL. **However the issue is that when I run the function like so:**

```
Dim st as String
st = "Hello"
Debug.Print TestString(ByVal st)
```

**I get a message saying bad DLL calling convention.** **On the other hand when I remove the `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)>` the function works BUT crashes shortly after printing `"Hello"`.**

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: you should use Return in VB.NET to send back the function value

Comment: This makes little sense, it is not ComVisible usage.  "I also obviously load the DLL" makes it worse.  If you use some kind of IL rewriter tool like Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports then you need to document that.

Comment: Right you are. Yes i use Gieseckes rewriter. I load the DLL during runtime using LoadDLL

Answer (score 0):

`Public Declare Function` is the syntax used to call functions *exported* from a DLL, this is a different mechanism from COM.

To use COM add a reference to the DLL, create an instance of the class containing `TestString` then call across that instance: `r = classInstance.TestString("Hello")`

Comment: I don't think so. This approach works well for other types of data types - Long, Integers etc. The function will work fine if I replace the String with Long for example. Only Strings are crashing my code for some reason